# BootStrap images sometimes overlapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having a problem with CSS Bootstrap on images that overlap on each others. The problem is also that sometimes it happens, sometimes it doesn't so it's very inconsistent.

I also noticed that if I click on F12 Dev tools, the images automatically get spaced properly.
I tried refreshing the cache pressing CTRL+F5 but the problem remains.

This is the website http://www.sdhealthy.com/productssnacks.html
and this is a sample of images overlapping ([picture](http://www.sdhealthy.com/overlapping.jpg)).

Anybody can please point me to what's wrong on the CSS code??

Comment: Are you using masonry or other jQuery to position the images? (I can't view your code, I'm on my phone browser)

Comment: @Gavin not sure, it's a bootstrap css template I've got from wrapbootstrap.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a look through your code and you are using the isotope jquery plugin to position and animate the divs with 'isotope-item class'.

I suspect that you need to add this part of your jquery...

```
$(".isotope-w").isotope({
itemSelector: '.item',
layoutMode: 'fitRows'
});
```

to a $(document).ready function.

This is because the isotope plugin is calculating heights of the divs before the images have finished downloading.

A "workaround" would be to manually add the height attribute to each of the images but I woould try and correct your jquery.

Firebug is also reporting an error:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined: $(document).ready(function () {
http://www.sdhealthy.com/productssnacks.html
Line 29
```

If your isotope code is already supposed to run on document ready, this error will prevent it from running.